# How to create irregular shape grid in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3

As I mentioned in my question, I want to create a grid which I defined the row and column widths. However, difference between them are not equal. The shape example in my mind is:

[image]

Comment: QGIS has a built-in tool to create a regular grid, but not to create an irregular grid. Perhaps you could create a regular grid with very narrow rows and columns, then dissolve neighboring rows and columns to created the desired widths. If you want to automate this process you'll need to figure out what rules the automation should follow.

Comment: You mean delete larger columns and rows

Comment: I was assuming a polygon grid, in which case you would dissolve adjacent rows to make them larger. If it was a line grid, then you would delete lines to make larger rows or columns.